# How To Span Table Headings?

Tags: legending

What I am doing wrong? I would like to get a header to the table and based on your code I tried this:

```
hdr = {{"Calculated Coordinates", SpanFromLeft}, {"No", "x", "y"}};
hdr1 = Grid[hdr, Frame -> All];

legendmarkers=Range@Length@data;                     
legendlabels=Map[Style[AccountingForm[#, 10], FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"] &, data, {-1}];                     
styledheaders=Style[#,Bold,FontSize -> 22,FontFamily -> "Calibri"] & /@ {hdr1};                     
legendGrd = Grid[Prepend[Transpose[Join[{legendmarkers}, 
Transpose[legendlabels]]], styledheaders], Frame -> All,
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"},
FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], Alignment -> {Center, Center},
Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[.5], {GrayLevel[.8]}}}]
```

The result is:

[image: Legend]

`Calculated Coordinates` should span all three columns, and `No`, `x`, and `y` should be the header of the corresponding columns.

**What must I do to get this?**

Comment: Perhaps the question title is not too well suited for those not familiar with the first part - consider rephrasing to help future visitors.

Comment: @Klett: Of course, I can do it. But don't you think, that the link to the first question of this topic will do it?

Comment: Not really - if you browse the questions, a meaningful, self-contained title is important. Having to retrace a question´s history to understand it is not beneficial. This question is about spanning table headings, not about a table in a legend.

Comment: I agree. I changed it and I hope it is now more or less ok

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
(* The following command imports your data from an image, see 
   http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/193 for an explanation *)

ToExpression@Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@Import["http://tinyurl.com/cbr4wkf","Data"]
```

Now the code

```
sh = Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Calibri"] &; 
hdr = {{sh@"Calculated Coordinates", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, sh /@ {"No", "x", "y"}};

leglbl = Map[Style[AccountingForm[#, 10]] &, data, {-1}];

legendGrd = Grid[
             Join[hdr, MapThread[Prepend, {leglbl, Range@Length@data}]], 
             BaseStyle  -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, Frame -> All, 
             FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
             Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[.5], GrayLevel[.5], {GrayLevel[.8]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Verde: Thanks a lot!!

Comment: _To the future visitors who might face a problem while running the codes_: for some unknown reasons, the `Uncompress` function might not work as expected. So you have to split the code in two parts. i.e. `str = FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[Import@"the-encoded-address","Data"];    `  and then concatenate the string with one or maybe two zeros, like this: `ToExpression@Uncompress[str<>"0"]`

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way. The trick is making the header part of the data.

```
hdr = {{"Calculated Coordinates", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {"No", 
    "x", "y"}};
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
legendmarkers = Range@Length@data;

legendlabels = 
  Map[Style[AccountingForm[#, 10], FontSize -> 20, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"] &, data, {-1}];

hdr[[2]] = 
  Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Calibri"] & /@ 
   hdr[[2]];
hdr[[1, 1]] = 
  Style[hdr[[1, 1]], Bold, FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Calibri"];
legendGrd = 
 Grid[hdr~Join~
   Transpose[Join[{legendmarkers}, Transpose[legendlabels]]], 
  Frame -> All, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
  Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[.5],GrayLevel[.5], {GrayLevel[.8]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ajasja: Thanks a lot!!